# Onchange value is not changing in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

In the react application.

This file is gonna update the to-do  list in the application

when I click on **Edit** button this component is pop-up the Modal.

The file name is **EditTodos.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Modal } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function EditTodo({ todo }) {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(todo.description);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  const updateDescription = async () => {
    try {
      const body = { description };
      const update = fetch(`http://localhost:3000/${todo.todo_id}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Button
        variant="warning"
        onClick={handleShow}
        data-target={`#id${todo.todo_id}`}
      >
        Edit
      </Button>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose} id={`id${todo.todo_id}`}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Edit Todo</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            value={todo.description}
            onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

So  I am not able to change the input field value.

`onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}`

I have done this but still I am not able to change input field value ?

whats going wrong in here.

Comment: `value={todo.description}` => `value={description}`

Comment: Cool. That helped. silly mistake!!!!

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't define state using props, thus you are having **two different sources of truth**,
the onChange function should come from parent,
though this is a bad practice the solution for this particular case would be

```
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            value={description}
            onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
          />
```

the reason being you are changing the description state in onChange but you are always keeping the value as description.toDo, which you are getting from parent component.

however, **avoid doing this**, keep a single source of truth, pass the onChange function as prop .